# No longer able to attach S3 bucket files to emails being sent by WordPress due to PHPMailer security update

Tags: core, bug, phpmailer

I've been trying to track down why my s3 bucket files are no longer being attached to automated emails being sent out by WordPress (using the Gravity Forms Entry Automation plugin).

I've been able to identify the latest version of PHPMailer being the reason why the attachments no longer get added. From the [PHPMailer ticket](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2355#issuecomment-858373284) response:

---

*This is due to a bug fix that also closed a major security hole. PHPMailer deliberately avoids being a client for HTTP or other protocols for file attachments because it is far too risky. The solution is to take on responsibility for fetching remote files yourself.*

*Instead of:*

```
$mail->addAttachment('s3://file.txt', 'file.txt');
```

*Do this:*

```
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents('s3://file.txt'), 'file.txt');
```

---

I reached out to the Gravity Forms authors as well as the Entry Automation authors and they both have said their plugins just generate raw notification objects and then use wp_mail() to pass the generated mail object off to the rest of my server to actually handle the sending.

Is there a way to get this working again without having to roll my WP version back? Or do y'all know how others are handling this issue?

One option would be to try to use the phpmailer_init hook, but I can't quite figure out how to do this to force using addStringAttachment.

Any suggestions? I'm kind of in a bind because the files that get attach must remain on S3 and not the local file system.

[Core ticket submitted here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53393)

Comment: So who exactly is making the addAttachment call, the Entry Automation plugin? I'd look for a hook in that around where it generates the email. Where do you configure the s3:// URLs in the admin site?

Comment: This sounds like a problem in WordPress Core introduced by a change to the PHPMailer dependency. It may be worth your while to [open a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/newticket) (if someone hasn't already) so that the core maintainers are aware of this problem.

Comment: @PatJ I opened up a ticket with Wordpress: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53393

Comment: @Rup I don't think the Entry Automation plugin is making the addAttachment call. They're using the default wp_mail function, which then uses PHPMailer. As for the s3:// URLs - I'm using the S3 Uploads plugin by Human Made to automatically dump everything that gets uploaded into a bucket.

Comment: Wasn't my close vote, but it wasn't obvious to me from the question that the addAttachment call was in core code from the question (but yes I see now it is). Hopefully you have raised a trac ticket for this as Tom suggested - please edit a link in? Your best bet might be to take a copy of wp_mail in a plugin (it's a pluggable function) and modify it to handle S3 URLs there. The best long-term solution is probably to get WP Core to add a filter to handle attachment URLs and fetch the contents, but trac is the way to go for that.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) does say that "The filenames in the $attachments attribute have to be filesystem paths" though, so S3 URLs aren't really supported by core. (Or maybe that's a recent edit after you raised the issue :-) ) But some hook here would be useful to let you support them yourself

Comment: Thank you @Rup. I ended up doing as you suggested for now. I created a copy of wp_mail in a plugin and modified it - if the attachment starts with "s3://mybucketname" then I call addStringAttachment. Otherwise it'll do the default addAttachment.

Comment: Where is the code that has the s3 bucket URL that you're using in your question? If new WP uses new PHPMailer that requires a change, then shouldn't the plugins update to do the change? Or the code that adds the file? WP doesn't have any S3 bucket functionality out of the box so it sounds like there's a large chunk of code and context missing from this question

Comment: If the code that creates the S3 bucket URL is in the plugins, then the plugins need to be updated. The fix suggested by the PHPMailer github issue is backwards compatible so there's no reason for them not to issue a fix

Comment: @Tom The addAttachment call is [in wp_mail in core](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.7.2/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L510) so the plugins aren't really responsible here. It sounds like some combination of plugin and config was passing an S3 URL into wp_mail as an attachment filename, and PHPMailer used to fetch the file from it itself (I guess using an URL handler registered and configured in a plugin), but the new version won't.

Comment: That's correct @Rup. PHPMailer authors told me that the fact that it used to previously fetch the file was a bug.